# what is the difference between writing custom method and custom filters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC filters provides a way of injecting the pre-processing and post-processing logic for actions and controllers. We can also write custom filters and decorate our action and controller with that attribute. The same thing can be achieved by writing methods before and after the action is executed. Then why do we use filters? what is the difference between writing custom method and custom filters?

Comment: Can you show what you mean by "Methods before and after the action is executed" (ie give some code showing what this would look like in a controller)

Comment: Using a filter allows you you write a one piece of code that can then be applied to multiple (or all) action methods

Comment: Instead of using action filters I can call a function in Action of Controller. So why do we need action filters in MVC? This is what my doubt is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i get by **custom method** you mean overriding controller pipeline methods like `OnActionExecuted` `OnResultExecuted` etc. If you implement your logic there, code which you write there will be exicuted on **All controller methods**. Moreover if you want to use this logic in other controllers in your application you had to create your CoreContoller class were you override methods and inherit it by other conrollers.

On the other side if you implement `ActionFilter` and register it in your MVC application you could use this logic on different controllers methods just by add attribute on top of your controller method. It's more flexible if you don't need your logic in all methods.